# jquery inarray always returning true

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a array with a array of locations like so

```
var pre_locations = [];
pre_locations.push(result.locations);
```

This returns the following

```
["BB,BD,BL,CA"]
```

But now i have some check boxes with the same values, so if any on the locations in the array have the same value as the checkbox, mark the checkbox as checked. But i have the following and its not working, i dont know why

```
$(".postcode_check").each(function(){
        if($.inArray($(this).val(), pre_locations) > 0){
             $(this).prop('checked', true);
        }
});
```

Comment: Can you show an example of the data (e.g. a console.log result) in pre_locations? And the HTML with .postcode_check?

Comment: the data is just an array from the database. So BB,BD,BL,CA

Comment: Unless you've made a typo, your array is a single string - is that intentional?

Comment: `$.inArray()` returns `-1` if the element was not found, not `0`. Your `> 0` condition looks wrong.

Comment: Yes, as Frederic states... `x >= 0`, `x > -1`, or `x !== -1` will work.

Comment: tried, now its checking the wrong checkbox...

Comment: Have you also looked at the comment from Rory? Try a console log to be sure your 'array' isn't a single string.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your locations, in your result, are coming back as a comma-separated string. This is based on an assumption given your scenario above. Just split the result and fix your condition to check for `> -1`.

This works fine.

```
var pre_locations = result.locations.split(',');

$(".postcode_check").each(function(){
  if ($.inArray($(this).val(), pre_locations) > -1) {
    $(this).prop('checked', true);
  }
});
```

## Demo

```js
var result = { locations : "BB,BD,BL,CA" };

$(document).ready(function() {
  createCheckboxes(['A','B','C','D'], 2); // Generate 16 checkboxes (AA->DD)

  var pre_locations = result.locations.split(',');

  $(".postcode_check").each(function(){
    if ($.inArray($(this).val(), pre_locations) > -1) {
      $(this).prop('checked', true);
    }
  });
});

// [IGNORE] These function are used to generate the checkboxes.
function createCheckboxes(alphabet, size) {
  $.each(permutations(alphabet, size), function(i, p) {
    $('body').append($('<div>').addClass('cb-wrapper')
      .append($('<label>').addClass('cb-label').html(p.join('')))
      .append($('<input type="checkbox">').addClass('postcode_check').val(p.join(''))));
    if (i % alphabet.length == alphabet.length-1) $('body').append($('<br>'));
  });  
}
function permutations(series, size) {
  return zeroFill(Math.pow(series.length,size)).map(function(r,i) {
    return zeroFill(size).map(function(c,j) {
      return series[Math.floor(i/Math.pow(series.length,j))%series.length];
    }).reverse();
  });
}
function zeroFill(n) {
  return new Array(n+1).join('0').split('');
}
```

```css
.cb-wrapper, .cb-label { display: inline-block; }
.cb-wrapper { width: 60px; }
.cb-label { display: inline-block; width : 24px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `concat` instead of `push`.

The [`push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) method adds new elements to the end of an array:

```
var a = [1, 2];
a.push([3, 4]);
// a is [1, 2, [3, 4]]
```

The [`concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) creates a new array by concatenating arrays:

```
var a = [1, 2];
var b = a.concat([3, 4]);
// b is [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rrngycLe/)